# How to include Query String in the route resolution in order to allow multiple Actions with the same Method, Route and Query String?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am converting an ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) application to ASP.NET Core MVC. This is strictly a conversion, I cannot make any breaking changes hence I cannot change any Routes or Methods. I am unable to match the same functionality in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Working ASP.NET MVC:

```
  [HttpPut]
  [Route("status")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateStatusByOrderGuid([FromUri] Guid orderGUID, [FromBody] POST_Status linkStatusModel)
  {

  }

  [HttpPut]
  [Route("status")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateStatusById([FromUri] Guid id, [FromBody] POST_Status linkStatusModel)
  {

  }
```

Not working, ASP.NET Core MVC.

I get an error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Code:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("status")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatusByOrderGuid([FromQuery] Guid orderGUID, [FromBody] POST_Status statusModel)
    {

    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("status")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatusById([FromQuery] Guid id, [FromBody] POST_Status statusModel)
    {

    }
```

I need to include the query parameters when it resolves which route. It should match based on whether `orderGUID` or `id` is in the query string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a single endpoint instead? You don't need to pass Guid's, since it's a GET operation, you can pass strings and cast them later. That way you can send one parameter or the other.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("status")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatus([FromBody] POST_Status statusModel, [FromQuery] string orderGUID = null, [FromQuery] string id = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderGUID))
    {
        // UpdateStatusByOrderGuid implementation here
        // Guid guid = Guid.Parse(orderGUID);

    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        // UpdateStatusById implementation here
        // Guid guid = Guid.Parse(id);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No valid GUID.");
    }
}
```

This endpoint should be compatible with both scenarios you specified.

Comment: Accepting because its less code and avoids creating a new class.

Answer (score 3):

You needs to custom `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`:

1.QueryStringConstraintAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class QueryStringConstraintAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string ValueName { get; private set; }
    public bool ValuePresent { get; private set; }
    public QueryStringConstraintAttribute(string valueName, bool valuePresent)
    {
        this.ValueName = valueName;
        this.ValuePresent = valuePresent;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        var value = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query[this.ValueName];
        if (this.ValuePresent)
        {
            return !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }
        return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("status")]
[QueryStringConstraint("orderGUID",true)]
[QueryStringConstraint("id", false)]
public void UpdateStatusByOrderGuid([FromQuery] Guid orderGUID,[FromBody]POST_Status model)
{

}

[HttpPut]
[Route("status")]
[QueryStringConstraint("id", true)]
[QueryStringConstraint("orderGUID", false)]
public void UpdateStatusById([FromQuery] Guid id, [FromBody]POST_Status model)
{

}
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

*Result:*
[image]